# Not getting the expected speedup with Cython

Tags: python, numpy, cython

Here are two code samples

```
def hough_transform_1(active_points, size_trame, size_max_song):
    m = np.linspace(0.95, 1.05, 11)
    p = np.linspace(-size_trame, size_max_song, size_max_song + size_trame + 1)
    acc = np.zeros([m.size, p.size])
    for m_i in m:
        for x_i, y_i in active_points:
            p_i = y_i - m_i * x_i + size_trame
            if p_i >= 0 and p_i < p.size:
                acc[m_i * 100 - 95, p_i] += 1
    #Return some value



DTYPE_INT = np.int
DTYPE_FLOAT = np.float

ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE_INT_t
ctypedef np.float_t DTYPE_FLOAT_t

@cython.boundscheck(False)
def hough_transform_2(np.ndarray[DTYPE_FLOAT_t, ndim=2] activepoints, sizetrame, sizemaxsong):
    cdef size_trame = sizetrame
    cdef size_max_song = sizemaxsong
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_FLOAT_t, ndim=2] active_points = activepoints
    cdef DTYPE_FLOAT_t x_i, y_i, m_i, p_i
    cdef float best_transformed
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_FLOAT_t, ndim=1] m = np.linspace(0.95, 1.05, 11).astype(DTYPE_FLOAT)
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_INT_t, ndim=2] acc = np.zeros([m.size, size_max_song + size_trame + 1], dtype=DTYPE_INT)
    cdef int i_range = m.size
    cdef int j_range = active_points.shape[0]
    for i in range(i_range):
        m_i = m[i]
        for j in range(j_range):
            x_i = active_points[j][0]
            x_i = active_points[j][1]
            p_i = y_i - m_i * x_i + size_trame
            if p_i >= 0 and p_i < size_max_song + size_trame + 1:
                acc[m_i * 100 - 95, p_i] += 1
    #Return some value
```

Those two functions (which detect lines with slope between 0.95 and 1.05 given a list of (x, y) input points) are equivalent, though the second one uses cython optimizations.

Testing their speed with (x is 1 or 2)

```
    time1 = time.time()
    for _ in range(100):
        hough_transform_x(points, self.length, self.length)
    time2 = time.time()
```

I get those results:

*35s for hough_transform_1 ; 20s for hough_transform_2*

Since using Cython on this type of function should result in a more significant speedup (I expected 100 times instead of 1.75 times), I think something is wrong in my cythonized code, but can't detect it. What did I miss?

Comment: It looks like you haven't `cdef`-ed your iterator variables, `i` and `j` as `int`s. That alone should give your code a big boost.

Comment: @Flav you should run `cython -a  file.pyx` and check if there are yellow lines in the generated `file.html`, especially inside the loops. If yes, you have undeclared types that are requiring more API calls...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, type everything. Secondly, actually type them.

These aren't typed(!) and should be typed in the argument list:

```
    cdef size_trame = sizetrame
    cdef size_max_song = sizemaxsong
```

This is redundant:

```
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_FLOAT_t, ndim=2] active_points = activepoints
```

This is fine:

```
    cdef DTYPE_FLOAT_t x_i, y_i, m_i, p_i
```

You don't use this:

```
    cdef float best_transformed
```

This would possibly be better hardcoded as a C array (`DTYPE_FLOAT_t[11]`):

```
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_FLOAT_t, ndim=1] m = np.linspace(0.95, 1.05, 11).astype(DTYPE_FLOAT)
```

These are fine:

```
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_INT_t, ndim=2] acc = np.zeros([m.size, size_max_song + size_trame + 1], dtype=DTYPE_INT)
    cdef int i_range = m.size
    cdef int j_range = active_points.shape[0]
```

`i` is untyped:

```
    for i in range(i_range):
        m_i = m[i]
```

`j` is untyped:

```
        for j in range(j_range):
```

This is pointless:

```
            x_i = active_points[j][0]
```

You want `active_points[j, 1]`:

```
            x_i = active_points[j][1]                
            p_i = y_i - m_i * x_i + size_trame
```

`0 <= pi < size_max_song + size_trame + 1`

```
            if p_i >= 0 and p_i < size_max_song + size_trame + 1:
                acc[m_i * 100 - 95, p_i] += 1
```

Comment: There is one point missing for acc[m_i * 100 - 95, p_i] += 1, where the indexes are not int which introduces some overhead (detected thanks to Saullo Castro's comment). The solution is to use variables m_i_index = int(m_i * 100 - 95) defined as int.
I won't come back on my clumsiness, but I didn't get the "This would possibly be better hardcoded as a C array (DTYPE_FLOAT_t[11])" part. Any way you could expand on that?

Comment: As in `cdef DTYPE_FLOAT_t[11] m = {0.95, ...}`. I can't test right now but there's a chance it'll look nicer seeing as `m` is constant. OTOH, it won't really matter.